# How to handle lxml errors without importing entire module?

Tags: python, error-handling, lxml, lxml.html

I have a Python (3.6) script running as a web spider. It grabs the content of a page, extracts the links and crawls them. It uses `lxml.html` to process the links, importing using

```
from lxml import html
```

I am trying to create custom responses to each error that it can come up against whilst running. I currently am handling Unicode, SSL, Redirect, Connection, and ContentDecode errors. I run into `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError` and `lxml.etree.XMLParseError` a lot. I have tried passing them via except-blocks, but it always stops when it runs into `NameError: name 'lxml' is not defined`, as I'm only importing `lxml.html` instead of the whole module.

Is there any way that I can catch the error(s) without importing the entire module?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the lxml errors just through `etree.(Error)`, ie. `etree.XMLSyntaxError` and `etree.ParseError`.

```
from lxml import etree
```

lxml also has [a nice page](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html) detailing every object in the `etree` module.